# Jquery and append function all time repit text

Tags: jquery, append

I use append function of jquery for add text and show div but when i use show me the text each time i go over the link trigger the effect

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$(".wm_1").mouseover(function() {

$("#web_tooltip").show(2000).append("Hello how are you?");
});

$("#web_tooltip").mouseover(function() {
$("#web_tooltip").hide(2000).fadeIn('slow');

});

});

</script>
```

When i go over the link trigger the effect show me the firt time "hello how are you .... if i go more times over the link show me 2 , 3 , 4 the text , and all time add the text to the div .....

Regards !!!

Comment: Cant really understand what youre asking for here. But since you are appending text it will add up. Try replacing `append` with `text`

Comment: I think no very difficult understand i need , jquery append add text , each time i use the function add text and repit , i want repit one time only and no continue add text in each time i go over the link  , i don´t know i must use empty for this .....

Comment: `empty().append("Hello how are you?");` or `.text("Hello how are you?");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".wm_1").mouseover(function() {
 $("#web_tooltip").empty();  
$("#web_tooltip").show(2000).append("Hello how are you?");

});
```

upd: try this if you need add info, but not replace (or some thing like that)

```
$(".wm_1").mouseover(function() {
$("#add_tooltip").remove();  
$("#web_tooltip").show(2000).append('<div id="add_tooltip">"Hello how are you?"');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `text()` instead:

```
 $("#web_tooltip").show(2000).text("Hello how are you?");
```

This will set the inner and not append a new text each time